# Enumeration and encoding of simplicial complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, simplicial-complexes

I'd like to know how to enumerate and encode all (abstract) [simplicial complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) of a given kind.

To start as simple as possible, consider the familiy $\mathcal{S}_n^{d}$ of simplicial complexes which consist of $n$ possibly intersecting $d$-dimensional simplices and their subsets (facets). How many such simplicial complexes are there  (up to isomorphism), and how to enumerate and/or encode them? Is there a standard encoding?

The following method to characterize or encode a simplicial complex in $\mathcal{S}_n^{d}$ is all I managed to come up with:

---

**Prerequisite**: Define $S_{i_1}S_{i_2}\dots S_{i_k}|_t$ to be the *proper intersection* of the sets (simplices) $S_{i_1}, S_{i_2}, \dots, S_{i_k}$ at some step $t$:

$$S_{i_1}S_{i_2}\dots S_{i_k}|_t = \bigcap_{\substack{i \in \{i_k\}\\i \leq t}} S_i \setminus \bigcup_{\substack{i \not\in \{i_k\}\\i \leq t}} S_i$$

---

1. Start with some $d$-simplex $S_1$ (with $d+1$ vertices).
2. The second simplex $S_2$ may have $n_{12} = \big|S_1S_2|_2\big| = |S_1 \cap S_2| \leq d$ vertices in common with $S_1$, i.e. the common facet may be the empty set, a vertex, an edge, a face, $\dots$, or a $d-1$-simplex.
3. The third simplex $S_3$ may have in common

   - $n_{13} = \big|S_1S_3|_3\big| = |(S_1 \cap S_3) \setminus S_2| \leq d$ vertices with $S_1$ (but not with $S_2$)
   - $n_{23} = \big|S_2S_3|_3\big| = |(S_2 \cap S_3) \setminus S_1| \leq d$ vertices with $S_2$ (but not with $S_1$)
   - $n_{123} = \big|S_1S_2S_3|_3\big| = |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3| \leq d$ vertices with $S_2$ and $S_3$ simultaneously,
     where $n_{13}, n_{23}, n_{123}$ have to fulfill the requirements:
   - $n_{123} \leq n_{12}$
   - $\sum_X n_{X3} \leq d + 1$
4. For the fourth simplex $S_4$ the proper intersections $S_1S_4|_4$, $S_2S_4|_4$, $S_3S_4|_4$, $S_1S_2S_4|_4$, $S_2S_3S_4|_4$, $S_1S_3S_4|_4$, $S_1S_2S_3S_4|_4 = S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4$ and their sizes $n_{X4}$ must be taken into account with the requirements

   - $n_{i4} \leq d$
   - $n_{X4} \leq n_{X}$
   - $\sum_X n_{X4} \leq d+1$

In sum a simplicial complex of $n$ $d$-dimensional simplices can be described/encoded by any sequence of numbers $n_X \leq d$ where $X$ runs over the subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with at least two elements (of which there are $2^{n} - n - 1$), and which fulfill the requirements above. This description is not unique, i.e. there may be different descriptions for the same simplicial complex.

I wonder, if this method is sound – or if it is flawed by some wrong assumptions or missing requirements. Furthermore I am looking for other enumerations or encodings.

Comment: Are you trying to enumerate up to isomorphism?

Comment: @SamHopkins: Yes, in principle, but I am aware that the sequences above will not do this job, i.e. to count them will not give the number of isomorphism classes of simplicial complexes.

Comment: If we ignore isomorphisms, your $S^d_n$ just correspond to selections of $n$ $d$-subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ for some $m$. I think it's clear it suffices to take $m=nd$ to get all possibilities.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Touché. This is the straight-forward encoding, and it takes $m\log_2 m$ bits to store it, right? My encoding takes $(2^n -  n - 1)\log_2 d$ bits to store it which seems much larger. But taking into account that my sequences consist of 0s mainly it might be less (because they can be compressed).

Comment: @SamHopkins: Another way to compare the encodings (yours: $n$ explicit $d$-subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,nd\}$, mine: a $(2^n - n - 1)$-sequence  of numbers $\leq d$) is the size of isomorphism classes: in your case it's the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,nd\}$, i.e. $(nd)!$, in my case it's the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, i.e. $n!$.